# "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error" in Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I've been working in Zend Framework for over a year now, but I've never encountered this issue.
I am developing on my local machine running PHP 5.2, Zend Framework 1.11.4, and MySQL 5. This is all running off Apache 2 on Ubuntu 10.04

My code is trying to add a permission record to the database. Here is my code:

```
protected function _add($resource, $description)
{
    $this->_sql = 'INSERT INTO Permissions (id, resource, description)
                    VALUES (NULL, :resource, :description)';
    $this->_params = array(
            ':resource' => $resource,
            ':description' => $description
    );
    $this->_query = $this->_db->prepare($this->_sql);
    $this->_query->execute($this->_params);
    $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll();
    if(count($this->_result) != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->_result[0];
}
```

The exception throw is happening on the line "$this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll();" and the message coming back is just "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error". Thats it. No error number or anything. Just GENERAL ERROR.
HOWEVER, when I check the Permissions table, the record has been successfully added. WTF?

I've been googling around for answers but I have found nothing that fixes the issue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->_result = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
```

instead of

```
$this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll();
```

I should have spotted that one earlier.

Answer (score 3):

`id` is your PK? Many RDBMS dont allow `NULL` for the PK, so this one *must* fail.

Update:
I see, mySQL allows `NULL` for an `PK AI`. However, I would omit it. ;)

Also I see its an `INSERT`-Statement and such a thing (afair) doesnt return anything. Maybe (just a guess ;)) you are looking for the [last inserted ID](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Adapter/Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract.html#lastInsertId)?

Comment: [[ $this->_sql = 'INSERT INTO Permissions (resource, description) VALUES (:resource, :description)'; ]] line change would fix should fix your problem as kingcrunch stated.

Comment: That only works, if `id` is defined as `PK AI` (what is very very likely ;))

Comment: id is the PK, but this is MySQL and the id field is set to auto-increment, so if I pass null... it just inserts the next value for the PK.

Comment: INSERT INTO Permissions (resource, description) VALUES (:resource, :description)

Comment: Stupid enter button... INSERT INTO Permissions (resource, description) VALUES (:resource, :description) did not fix this problem... I am thinking that in Zend I can't do a fetchAll on an insert. That would make sense. I'll update this post when I test that out.

Comment: Oh, I see, its `INSERT`. In my oppinion: No, it doesnt make sense. What do you expect to get there?